# Infinite scroll code not working using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll, infinite-scroll, nginfinitescroll

Here is a code I am working on for infinite scroll using angularJS. But the code is not working, also shows no error. Here is my code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html  ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
li {
  height: 120px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

#fixed {
    height: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
}

</style>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div id="fixed" when-scrolled="loadMore()" >
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="i in items">{{i.id}}</li>
  </ul>  
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){

    $scope.items = [];
    
    var counter = 0;
    $scope.loadMore = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            $scope.items.push({id: counter});
            counter += 10;
        }
    };
    
    $scope.loadMore();
}

angular.module('scroll', []).directive('whenScrolled', function() {
    return function(scope, elm, attr) {
        var raw = elm[0];
        
        elm.bind('scroll', function() {
            if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
                scope.$apply(attr.whenScrolled);
            }
        });
    };
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think there is some problem with the ng-app or ng-controller.  As I am new to angularjs please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you get an error in console?

Comment: Yes, Now I am getting an error. You can copy my code as it is  or run the snippet to see the error. Thankx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the fact that you have lots of syntax mistakes I don't see any troubles with code. It [works](http://plnkr.co/edit/t14hbgowBzbZZsplF6vC?p=preview) when the following is corrected.

Wrong variable reference:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);//'app' variable declared but later 
//referenced as 'myApp'
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
```

controller function missing `);` in the end

And a new module declared for some reason for a directive and not injected into `myApp`. Unless you have strong reasons that you clearly understand, don't spawn unnecessary modules. Get the same one you already defined

```
app.directive('whenScrolled', function() {
```